# Using kinematic rigidbody with full kinematic contacts with oncollisionenter2d not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Dynamic has worked but I want it to not get affected by physics
I tried turning all the constraints on dynamic but it's not working

Comment: I don't know when will the edit show up but it's unity2d I put unity and it defaulted to unity3d tag

Comment: I made it so it logs when oncollisionenter happens but it only logs on certain areas like slopes maybe its the platform motor I got from https://github.com/cjddmut/Unity-2D-Platformer-Controller

Comment: When I removed the platformer motor it seemed to work but it's really good and better than I could I do

Answer (score 0):

I was using the platform motor2d from https://github.com/cjddmut/Unity-2D-Platformer-Controller It had a minimum distance from environment variable and I set to zero and It fixed it